# remote rejected master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recieve an error while pushing rails code to heroku.

```
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 1.75 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: !   Could not complete the action. Please try again later.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/dishcuss-api.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dishcuss-api.git'
```

I have tried the few methods , including rollback heroku and git pull , but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run the migration on heroku:

`heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible solutions to your problem:

1. It's possible that you didn't run your latest migrations on your Heroku server. In that case do `heroku run rake db:migrate`.
2. The other option is that this is caused by their SSL certificate that isn't valid any more as of a few hours ago; they're working on that.